# Use condition to modify data points in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

I am interested in using a condition and illustrating it in `ggplot2`- specifically, if the absolute difference between T2 and T1 is greater than one (i.e. `abs(T2 - T1) > 1`), then I color (in black) that particular data point on "T2".

However, the problem is that I'm unsure how to do this in code - and sufficiently, at that.

This is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(directlabels)
df[, c(2:13)]<-lapply(lapply(df[,2:13], as.character), as.numeric)
df<-data.matrix(df)
dat = melt(subset(df, select = c("Value","Condition")),id.vars = "Condition")
dat<-dat[1:40,]
dat[,1]<-c(rep(1:20,2))
dat[,2]<-c(rep("T1",20),rep("T2",20))
colnames(dat)[2]<-"Time"
ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(dat$value))), color = Time, group=Time), 
       data = dat, label = value) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Time, size=4)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(dat$value))), 2)), 
            method="smart.grid", color = "black") +
  xlab("Items") + ylab("Values") + ggtitle("Line Graph")
```

This is the chart:

[image]

This is the `dput()` output:

```
dput(df)
structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, -2.77799880286286, -5.50944520378118, 1.88836435580497, 
-5.58406005229873, 4.44735158239659, -6.82897889434699, -2.1716215347289, 
-6.24523609922322, 2.76458526645867, 5.48271803933499, -6.14473005987329, 
-1.5417866304646, -6.62612955305313, 3.70896578961902, -3.4179458605496, 
1.82132726703399, -0.9280760020449, -1.37160088556748, 3.19524553300007, 
-4.95347572092664, 2.85061161249751, -1.86116126313546, 5.02499132690551, 
-0.589243309301991, 4.82762042912157, 0.169968256089778, -2.19470633021516, 
-1.49426127124266, 4.0326779589342, 5.48630151034464, -3.04465732022428, 
2.74719269076656, -3.42432474774963, 7.17005454165613, 3.29173512430591, 
6.15013558100303, 3.37225798878721, 3.16447670131925, 5.76818087898048, 
-2.47667639336567, 2.9410259668896, 5.24942846129507, 2.95615407147939, 
2.53728090334437, 4.45378164065699, 4.99724304408089, 3.41151350933973, 
6.5558635012366, 2.9382584815192, 5.553396018278, 5.66712392721592, 
3.70722135586978, 4.91809317051882, 4.43567725100426, 4.85957115798564, 
1.13776426116428, 1.45147180831314, 2.93845495539568, 3.69799943125266, 
5.58188967776966, 1.70671301941748, 1.87716808779163, 4.52979801504946, 
4.02882680021941, 4.47697541167503, 2.00725924508944, 1.47797506789819, 
2.81083558050484, 1.73059487384682, 2.93638454645181, 2.11798237001241, 
1.56476900094613, 2.8051256046925, 4.91148661864085, 2.39984241054436, 
6.01680803527874, 3.45216832637263, 3.86786912841398, 5.14510980394688, 
1.96226240820569, 1.46769784381359, -4.23315686452177, 1.34462318507629, 
-4.13803301156994, 3.46433009466818, -0.688603097392773, -0.864647679558938, 
-2.41397623113989, 1.9258218879359, 2.12843971854681, -3.90465123084954, 
2.85141616984777, -0.425193435370328, 1.26215227718771, -0.443706739548623, 
1.99409077435011, 0.993384901206013, -1.2539971894181, 2.16674821850839, 
-1.14332285049104, 1.2877641319428, -5.0790640948831, 2.16491856402794, 
-5.7209806024071, 2.42987914111965, -0.0338801558976428, -4.05418787838149, 
-4.66851179473313, 2.84008251058085, 3.82691297178971, -4.84551053369274, 
0.081540160504272, -2.15526245166253, -0.176870366357385, -0.877844323553365, 
-0.258594819181801, 0.430370682726835, -3.49027845749809, 0.331486593462475, 
-4.37685606663863, 1.12112630791616, 3.84715347197235, 1.47596355786357, 
4.04476901846664, 3.22121946000162, 2.13221568496659, 0.652861523704772, 
1.86053940564217, 2.18750685665418, 2.22409039914394, 3.31684834987514, 
2.37433623873005, 1.96881662200605, 0.623734917918608, 0.938645410686527, 
1.6194531430081, 1.0572785346611, 1.80192982083783, 2.30928777991719, 
1.33090194123859, 2.30457009724777, 4.44215663384225, 1.9456455099693, 
5.5491241262749, 2.90365637378558, 1.35352785699859, 4.00797171059206, 
4.54513631393887, 4.11261546736008, 4.72222683677877, 4.77697916123432, 
0.401623824136378, 2.80147690765104, 1.44060736377897, 1.20626242635587, 
0.335776941897886, 0.870712988549501, 2.82555530959146, 1.02961044767606, 
4.40677773658637, 1.08733086714195, -4.58237221368757, 0.500775366216656, 
-2.24308867788549, 0.923483146787494, 0.983312535004998, -0.506717556382614, 
-0.704911411238621, 0.789477493179571, -0.263046689942195, -2.43579693951632, 
1.14410003345258, 0.903308056174724, 2.56662144872607, -2.83034226881492, 
1.72659090224099, 1.48023061106132, -5.30639508766639, 1.11099764546048, 
-4.19126050554502, -1.05089323769677, 1.54372391361437, -1.56352981645499, 
2.93127137918086, 0.501362777825551, 0.346307986678131, -0.344374655196894, 
1.91773468184104, -3.61476249608386, -4.5451606571318, 3.13201396026136, 
1.10416369238183, -1.6515940027554, -2.30082843813389, -3.24938747503207, 
1.64169861482598, 1.25939003291661, -3.22315899193569, 1.02901350502441, 
-0.307596191022465, 0.607172870047824, 3.18670101637946, 1.18329147532167, 
1.73931931950462, 1.08642392258211, 1.75963707713729, 0.598209932001034, 
0.71799058314335, 1.71030492189432, 1.86973358441346, 1.96214081370305, 
2.12865325016569, 1.86580109155386, 1.99385141233056, 1.9304518662167, 
1.67887046756132, 1.89380653935655, 3.51584085505365, 1.59008281821586, 
2.63776915192942, 2.01324356378045, 1.92426610560178, 2.01351363124494, 
2.09837681150714, 0.564283583646676, 1.94900394722626, 2.03932275387923, 
1.77291581898077, 3.31700177429301, 3.56054613450095, 2.48818428369487, 
1.56026700091836, 0.895001669911228, 2.45494944723334, 2.49614852057026, 
0.980970610101227, 1.2327710192819, 1.90720295041313, 1.52990252674699, 
2.24055435759981, -1.73119862850002, 1.0216815782015, -3.08104316219856, 
0.742062185068333, 0.637759900635563, 0.313639004730233, -1.04389320657185, 
-0.168343229992165, -3.50957435418526, -0.805146224350448, 1.89813728483076, 
2.11234302788144, 0.65291943976787, -1.66538732232707, 2.06761784535478, 
1.07368735890632, 1.18116854535688, 4.35475739971616, 2.4291449411867, 
2.66250155475042, -3.07984879560606, -0.982161144689049, -2.17134923344571, 
-1.04981167576708, 1.02982534690544, 0.0739956440116955, -3.53127755255401, 
-0.983920844230844, -2.4237703274689, 1.1137895914255, 1.88292910019935, 
1.88115084031971, -0.528776945568896, -2.51963703622653, -1.21224167026079, 
-0.00733001295324706, 0.489654593226242, 1.64244792747709, 1.97849384758581, 
-2.73222532916273, 1.30664000318633, 2.51152591709287, 2.3610878671388, 
2.68821086374941, 0.756179657571522, 1.31406083006702, 0.502270349719078, 
0.877048724863803, 3.27032715567304, 2.02817740776692, 3.13885298082316, 
1.69040861120208, 1.44621246031203, 2.72542768045343, 1.65168160243242, 
1.0613486997877, 1.36730424217884, 4.70242398349343, 1.47846129638809, 
2.90982977301074, 1.6415398652502, 1.80971856575705, 1.80126834813569, 
2.30402758910142, 0.453944083869317, 1.44975937874442, 2.76072379297129, 
2.05179959258098, 1.96034746487189, 2.46972904118759, 1.52646811270462, 
1.68792219492701, 0.942581896362376, 1.43412205194171, 1.32429401657411, 
0.74028817732329, 0.934463299964322, 1.75899225369897, 1.73093691569634, 
2.44604484756581, -0.81707831508849, -0.101640659501738, -0.199372098325561, 
-0.731350355341286, -1.50185595150164, -2.15385646903906, 0.341362372622556, 
0.0717794525986977, -0.674790643399441, -1.02832745657856, -0.807289055054835, 
-0.273625459413725, -1.89714842447061, -2.72809814735591, -1.87304656922355, 
-1.75211939950996, -0.179811464643785, -2.47054193194854, 0.875985668308142, 
-0.87107168324186, 2.88411862461663, 1.13350717882749, 0.881717271657503, 
-0.680906046795757, -0.00986342272375014, -1.30401468178664, 
-0.718835987756961, -0.274692056120372, 2.25741424032245, -0.733100021865329, 
0.410517365563169, 2.17391980797268, -1.72828926038821, 2.32332016354502, 
-0.35469728539741, 0.547277997817807, 1.9063894042504, -1.38302649805023, 
4.22638973141164, -0.834303241714936, 1.29217284997393, 0.920346644301893, 
1.41581152942903, 1.68422758278347, 1.46401543006383, 2.59715468920863, 
0.671463941291187, 0.391827833427845, 0.830409256044418, 1.51196965141483, 
1.25622927071156, 0.633365193686345, 2.45392708107328, 2.15333609263216, 
2.38240811335379, 1.93971167427935, 0.20678171606071, 3.13623314571654, 
1.2020914095021, 1.45795937568229, 2.79079354402284, 1.96590935476358, 
1.02143633694447, 0.891283752569684, 0.516990294238038, 1.51976159759388, 
0.454055895284961, 0.80654340174185, 2.14646393071754, 1.8189172212192, 
1.21142394057217, 1.84172112667041, 1.89688920138007, 2.59190659576094, 
0.810205134547583, 0.731657346597015, 1.70901155496863, 1.21455024297602, 
3.52967217716404, 0.754338180088601, -1.29611694379859, -2.02848235962263, 
-1.88100885357239, 0.00782681463321539, 1.26584897977176, -1.11647972403716, 
-1.087284846439, -0.0952271741106955, 0.131800629971024, 3.72882805009692, 
-0.417680991612429, -2.40929168614188, -0.954139748948513, -0.185182454834748, 
-2.31198436769972, -0.601593634688318, -0.358753304703935, 0.264121584587967, 
0.877095537027569, -1.04128766257684, -1.34634072546986, -0.711769725913958, 
1.56173816149338, 2.1056023883716, 0.849351763165274, -0.333430738703158, 
0.867470294719106, 3.06609445431155, 0.156548761957329, 3.23204999230325, 
0.594583943629732, -0.591859747610828, -0.771489333759391, -1.61849385298721, 
-0.994837577062622, -0.471029875852922, 0.494956557283429, 0.869778487578066, 
0.664401960629288, 0.705356572496125, 1.71969313558994, 1.22514664503418, 
2.43615010778863, 0.90543774831495, 1.47968455180469, 1.58025802579494, 
1.09964089759256, 0.424333680265671, 0.588266235029791, 3.134216074508, 
0.789168044524916, 1.29409026043504, 1.39999018584329, 0.685175161870907, 
2.1240505562516, 1.0118137455611, 0.274816868206689, 1.24463783903865, 
1.32271783466684, 0.839356205249546, 2.26239611885107, 0.81461450270275, 
1.04915471241655, 1.58417059541705, 1.43402870983137, 0.922256074093675, 
0.610663047712594, 1.67973206887357, 1.06535791664458, 3.55339972908477, 
1.29706172782603, 0.700609412377317, 1.10881444509497, 2.36973842570586, 
1.54286536846859, 0.39414111430605, 0.594818127352406, 0.990174530659289, 
1.66222872402804, 0.822538694893619), .Dim = c(40L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20"), c("Condition", "group1.value", 
    "group1.se", "group2.value", "group2.se", "group3.value", 
    "group3.se", "group4.value", "group4.se", "group5.value", 
    "group5.se", "group6.value", "group6.se")))
```

Applying the suggested commanded, the majority of the 20 data points for "T2" should be in black.

Comment: do you mean change the label to a bold black font or make the data point itself black? In the second case, what do you mean by bold data point (how should it differ from the other data points except for the color?)

Comment: also, could you `dput(df)`

Comment: @scoa, I see you point. I meant that instead of the data point being colored by the "T2" condition, it is colored in as black. Let me make the edits in the original post.

Comment: can you post your data?

Comment: @scoa, I just did. Sorry it took a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a second `geom_point()` subsetting dat to the only values where the diff between T1 and T2 > 1.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(directlabels)

df <- as.matrix(df)

rn <- row.names(df)
df <- data.frame(df)

dat <- df %>% select(Condition,group1.value) %>%
  mutate(item=as.numeric(rn)) %>%
  spread(Condition,group1.value) %>%
  rename(T1 = `1`,T2 = `2`) %>%
  mutate(diff=abs(T2-T1)) %>%
  gather(Time,value,-item,-diff)


ggplot(aes(x = item, y = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(dat$value))), color = Time, group=Time), 
       data = dat, label = value) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Time, size=4)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(dat$value))), 2)), 
            method="smart.grid", color = "black",hjust=1,vjust=1) +
  xlab("Items") + ylab("Values") + ggtitle("Line Graph") +
  geom_point(data=filter(dat,diff>1,Time=="T2"),aes(x=item,y=value),color="black",size=4)
```

[image]

On a side-note, you may want to rethink your data organization. Your df is half-way between a long and wide data.frame and that doesn't work well with ggplot (that's why I used `spread` and then `gather`.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the time to do this. I definitely agree with you in that I should better streamline my code.

Comment: how did you deal with the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'dat' not found`? I got the below code to work, but I had to run it twice:....
`dat <- df %>% select(Condition,dim1.scale.value) %>%
  mutate(Subscale=rn) %>%
  spread(Condition,dim1.scale.value) %>%
  mutate(diff=abs(as.numeric(dat$Post)-as.numeric(dat$Pre))) %>%
  gather(Time,value,-Subscale,-diff)`

Comment: `mutate(diff=abs(as.numeric(dat$Post)-as.numeric(dat$Pre)))` should be ` mutate(diff=abs(as.numeric(Post)-as.numeric(Pre)))` because dat does not exist before the chain has been evaluated. In a dplyr pipe, you can call variables directly, without their dataframe